# Randomly fade in div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Any help here is much appreciated. I would like to use jQuery to solve the following...

There are two divs.  I would like to randomly fade in one of the divs (green or red), wait a few seconds, then fade it away. Then randomly fades in another one.  I've tried using `math.random();`but I can't seem to get it working correctly.

So basically it chooses either the red or green div.. fades it away after a few seconds, randomly chooses the red or green div... then fades it away after a few seconds.  And It just keeps repeating.

html:

```
<div id="one">This is the first block</div>
<div id="two">This is the second block</div>
```

css:

```
#one { 
    background: red;
    width:300px; 
    height:100px; 
}
#two { 
    background: green;
    width:300px; 
    height:100px; 
}
```

Comment: if you have only 2 divs and each time you want to fade in, fade out and then fade in the OTHER one, it will never really be random no? or it's ok to select the same element twice in a row?

Comment: Wow! Fast responses, each one worked in its on way. Unfortunately Stack Overflow says I need more of a reputation to Upvote... but otherwise I'd Upvote all. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give both `divs` a class name like `.fade` for easier to manage.

Then you can do like this:

```
(function randomFade() {
    var fadeDivs = $('.fade'),
        el = fadeDivs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * fadeDivs.length));        
    el.fadeIn('1000').delay(2000).fadeOut('1000',randomFade);   
})();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gx8jR/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
function fadeRandomly() {
   // fade both out at first
   $('#one').fadeOut(/* duration */); 
   $('#two').fadeOut(/* duration */); 
   if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
      $('#one').fadeIn(/* duration */);
   } else {
      $('#two').fadeIn(/* duration */); 
   }
}

setInterval(fadeRandomly, /* duration between animations */);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;//outputs either 1 or 2

if (rnd == 1) {
  $('#one').fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
} else {
  $('#two').fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

something like: I added a function just in case you have more divs to deal with you and you want to expand the scope of your fades.

```
var a = ['one', 'two']; // the name of your divs
function fadeRandomDiv(min, max) {
  var divtofade =  a[Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)];
   // delay 4 seconds, then fade out
  jQuery( "#" + divtofade ).fadeIn( "slow" ).delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
}

fadeRandomDiv(1, a.length - 1)
```

if you want to repeadedly call it.

```
  // every 3 seconds call the function
   setInterval(function(){
       fadeRandomDiv(1, a.length - 1);
    }, 3000);
```